# Interior of simplex that is a proper face not open?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If a simplex $\sigma$ is a proper face of another simplex $\tau$, why is its interior not open in $\tau$?

I can't seem to understand as, let's take $\sigma=ab$, a line segment that is a proper face of $\tau=abc$, a triangle. Then the interior of $\sigma$ is an open line which should be open in $\tau$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is a two-dimensional simplex in $\mathbb R^2$, then $\sigma$ is a compact connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$, so a subset $S$ of $\sigma$ is open in the induced Euclidean topology if and only if for point $p$ in $\sigma$, you can find an open ball $B$ with center $p$ such that $B\cap S\subset \sigma\cap S$.

Any nonempty proper face $\tau$ of $\sigma$ is either a point or a segment, in both case, they would have Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb R^2$, so it is not possible to find such balls.